# Regular expression for replacing space with underscore in jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

i using jmeter and i want to capture the response of previous request but before sending it to next request i want to replace space with underscore , if any.

i am just able to capture the response using regular expression extractor  but unable to replace it with proper valid parameter.

using this regex - `([^|]+)`

for example - i have request 1 whose response is - `India | South Africa` , so here if i get `South Africa` as a parameter for my next request then first ,i want to replace space with underscore so i want value as- `South_Africa` .
can anyone help?

Comment: Try using a [JavaScript function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript), `${__javaScript(${varnamehere}.trim().replace(/\s+/g\, '_'))}`.

Comment: is this a regular expression?

Comment: `\s+` is a regex pattern.

Comment: Note you may use other scripting languages, Groovy seems to be recommended in case performance is important. See [instructions and comparison here](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance).

Comment: yes i have used groovy

Comment: So, the problem is fixed? Please add to the question or as an answer.